# Creating user from rails console command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am newbie in Ruby, I am trying to install one app that says:

```
lobsters$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.8)

irb(main):001:0> User.create(:username => "test", :email => "test@example.com", :password => "test", :password_confirmation => "test", :is_admin => true, :is_moderator => true
irb(main):002:0> Tag.create(:tag => "test")
```

When I run rails console, it outputs "create some file" So how do I create user?

Comment: Did you run the command in the projects directory?

Comment: What is the output of each of those commands?

Comment: You're missing the closing parens for User.create( ... )

Comment: "create some file" is what rails console outputs?

Answer (score 19):

Try this :

```
User.create!(username: "test", email: "test@example.com", password: "test", password_confirmation: "test", is_admin: true, is_moderator: true)
```

In practice, Ruby programmers reserve ! to adorn the names of methods that do something unexpected, or perhaps a bit dangerous

> So in this case, the "unexpected" result is that an exception is
>   raised instead of just failing and returning false.

Comment: You should probably explain what your answer do (even though it seems pretty simple and straightforward). It's not just about solving a problem. ;)